# Is there a way for AutoIt to get JavaFX application's text

Tags: javafx, autoit

I am new to AutoIt and I'm using its java bridge and I really liked it. But from what i understand even though it support swing and swt it does not support JavaFX. When I use it with a javaFx application, I cant get the texts with its finder tool. So is there a way to get around this? A simple way to get texts and other things from JavaFX application for test verification purposes? Thank you for all your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check JABSimpleSpy that is a spy based on java accessibiliy bridge build with AutoIt

https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_control_.28click.2C_edit_etc.29_an_external_.28html.29_application.3F